# Hide widgets/plugins from dashboard

Tags: dashboard, admin-menu, admin-bar

I have two plugins in the dashboard, [SEO Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/), and for security reasons I want to hide these from dashboard. How to do that?

I tried to hide the SEO Wordpress with this:

```
// Remove Admin Dashboard menus
 function wp_admin_dashboard_remove_menus() {
     global $menu;
     $restricted = array(('Comments'), __('Users'), __('Updates'), __('wpseo_dashboard'));
     end ($menu);
     while (prev($menu)){
         $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
         if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){
             unset($menu[key($menu)]);
         }
     }
 }

 add_action('admin_menu', 'wp_admin_dashboard_remove_menus');
```

Tried many combinations like:

```
__('wpseo')
__('wp-seo')
__('wp_seo')
```

But the SEO menu did not hide.

Comment: Have you researched anything here? Please, tell us what you found and why it didn't work.

Comment: The WordPress Seo menu is already limited to users who can `manage_options` ie. admins, do you have admins who you don't want viewing/using it? I'd have a similar question for the other plugin if i could find the relevant piece of source code, but that's too many files to check via the plugin svn manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Wordpress SEO

If you want to remove the admin menu:

[image: wpseo]

you can do that with:

```
function hide_wpseo() {
       remove_action('admin_menu', 'zeo_options_menu');
}
add_action( 'init', 'hide_wpseo');
```

where it will be removed for all users.

### WordPress SEO by Yoast

To hide the admin menu:

[image: admin menu]

and the admin menu bar:

[image: admin menu bar]

one can use:

```
function hide_yoastseo() {
    remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wpseo_admin_bar_menu',95);
    remove_menu_page('wpseo_dashboard');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_yoastseo');
```

where it will be hidden for all users.

### Custom Content Type Manager

Here one can hide the admin menu:

[image: admin menu]

from all users with:

```
function hide_cctm() {
    remove_menu_page('cctm');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'hide_cctm');
```

Comment: It's already limited to users with `manage_options`, see: [source here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/tags/1.4.7/admin/class-admin.php).

Comment: @birgire i refer to Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. For the code which is above, this is not work.

Comment: @t31os thanks for noticing it ;-) I updated the code to remove it for all users.

Comment: @MikeD I hope I got the right plugin this time ;-)

Comment: Yes @bitgire, the code is right. Now i want to hide the Custom Content Type Manager from dashboard.

Comment: ok great, please add the link to these  two plugins in your question.

Comment: @birgire What exactly you mean? In my first question i ask what i want to do.

Comment: I mean to provide the plugin link on wordpress.org, so I will be sure to check the right plugin code ;-)

Comment: @bilgire i edit the first question. Is it right or you want to do something else?

Comment: perfect, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Unbelievable. That was three times (out of five) a _slightly wrong name_. Right, bilgire? Err, bitgire, no bigire. ;) Sorry, I just had to share my amazement.

Comment: @birgire To complete this, is there any way to remove the SEO check metabox?

Comment: You can do that from the `SEO > Titles & Metas > Post Types` settings, just check the `WordPress SEO Meta Box: Hide`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide it for a specific kind of user like an author? If so, you can use the Advanced Access Manager plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

With this plugin you can decide what the user(group) has access to in the backend and also what permissions he/she has.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to hide it for the admin. Sorry, but i don't want to use a plugin for this. I try to solve it with a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

For removing plugin's menu from multisite dashboard

```
foreach($GLOBALS[ 'menu' ] as $key => $value) {

    remove_menu_page($value[2]);

}
```

For adding menu use `add_menu_page();`